# Git checkout after updating a folder to submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

1. I have a repository with `module` folder under `master` branch.
2. I created a new branch `branch` from `master`, and switched to it.
3. I deleted the `module` folder with its contents, and committed changes.
4. I added a submodule in `module` with almost same contents, and committed changes.
5. I did `git checkout master`, and got `error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout` with list of the `module` folder contents.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was easy. I should do exactly what the error tells me - delete the conflict folder :)

1. `rm -R module`
2. `git checkout master`